# Django: sending e-mail with ajax - security issue

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, security

I am working with Django and after few tasks that require ajax calls I would like to send an email:

```
$.when($.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{% url 'check_status' %},
            data: {'params':'data'},
        }),
).then(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{% url 'send_email' %}",
        data: {'email': email}
    });
});
```

I have set up CSRF tokens and the requests are post. However, I am concern with that somebody can use my send_email view to send unwanted e-mails.

I would like to restrict the view to be used only for this given template/context not eg. from python requests library. Is it even possible?

Comment: Isn't that what the csrf token already does?

Comment: I am not sure, that's why I am asking.

Comment: CSRF without other checks (form validity for example) won't help you here, since a user can first use a GET request to retrieve a CSRF token, and use it for posting.  You can limit your view to logged in users using [`@login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) or [`LooginReqiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).  How would you logically define a user/session that shold be allowed to send an email (in contrast to someone who is not allowed to send an email)?

Comment: I agree, I just wrote a small script using python requests library that sends the e-mail. I can check also if the request is ajax but that can be tricked too. The portal is open and does not require login - it just sends requests to other servers and is getting the answers from them. After the answers are received they should be sent to the user (user provides an e-mail in the form). So ideally, e-mail should be restricted to the user that actually filled the form ie. posted the form data not just "got" token with get. I am thinking about changing the strategy here.

Comment: I think I can use sessions to achieve this. Eg. form data would be saved in session and accessed in send_email thus not exposed to outside.